# Why do I get this mergeDebugResources error?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting this error when the app tries to build. The stack question I've seen on this appears to use an out-of-date version of gradle and changing the version manually doesn't seem to do anything at all except for make the gradle unable to sync.

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
 > C:\Users\Brian\AndroidStudioProjects\UENI\app\src\main\res\drawable\divider2.png:
 Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
 org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
 'C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.0\aapt.exe''
 finished with non-zero exit value 42

 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem (I believe). I had JPG image using PNG tag and the compiler picked up on it, changing tags to the proper one fixed the issue.